# Table with expandable rows which contain another table using Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, table

I'm trying to achieve exactly the same table. However i'm unable to add the inner table which appears on row click. As i wanted to achieve this using visualforce (No Aura), please let me know what i might be missing. Thanks

VF:

```
                     <table>
                        <thead >
                            <tr>
                                <th>Opportunity</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Start</th>
                                <th>End</th>
                                <th>Budget</th>
                                <th>More ($)</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!wrap}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{!wrap.a}</td>
                                    <td>{!wrap.b}</td>
                                    <td>{!wrap.c}</td>
                                    <td>{!wrap.d}</td>
                                    <td>{!wrap.e}</td>
                                    <td>{!wrap.f}</td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                <!--Inner Table-->
                                <tr>
                                    <div>
                                    <table id="newtable">
                                        <thead id="newth">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th colspan="1">Jan</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Feb</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Mar</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Apr</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">May</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Jun</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Jul</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Aug</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Sep</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Oct</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Nov</th>
                                                <th colspan="1">Dec</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </div>
                                </tr>                                    
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give more context?  The screenshot tables & columns don't match up with your VF page.  Also, relevant controller code would be helpful as well

Comment: Hi Brian, pls ignore the screen shot content. I'm trying to show a list of Opps in a table and when any table row is clicked, i would like to show additional information in a table whose content will be amount divided by month (Jan to Dec). The prototype which im trying to achieve is similar to what the example screenshot achieved.